# Is there any relation between the suffix "-ship" and actual ships?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

I am curious if there is actual relation between all nouns ending in *-ship*, such as *relationship, citizenship, sportsmanship*, etc. with the vessel for transporting people or goods over the sea?

Comment: While it does seem to be true that from a practical standpoint, there is no relationship between the suffix ship and a sea or space fairing vessel, it's perhaps noteworthy that your question is a good one, and furthermore, that there are some parallels which could be drawn. Now to further complicate matters I can inform you that I myself am a dread pirate, who was told it could be acceptable to create new words using the suffix ship, and as a writer, that encouraging concession is rather like a ship itself.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369192/what-are-the-many-meanings-of-the-suffix-ship-and-can-it-reasonably-be-applied

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*-ship* is added to a noun to establish status or condition.

1. Indicating a state or a condition, e.g. to be in a friendship.
2. Indicating the qualities belonging to a class of people, e.g. craftsmanship.
3. Indicating office or profession, e.g. ambassadorship.

Quote from http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=19990225:

> The suffix -ship has been studied in
>   some detail, but most of that detail
>   is irrelevant to all but the most
>   hardcore etymologist. The most
>   important thing, in terms of its
>   origin, is that it is unrelated to the
>   word ship meaning 'a vessel,
>   especially a large seagoing vessel'.
>
> -ship is a suffix used to form nouns of state or condition, chiefly added
>   to nouns and especially personal
>   nouns. In Old English it was widely
>   used with adjectives and participles,
>   but only two of these survive
>   (hardship and worship, from an
>   adjective meaning 'worthy').
>
> The uses can be divided into
>   ever-finer distinctions, but there are
>   some basic categories. It can denote
>   'quality; condition' (kinship;
>   friendship 'the condition of being a
>   relative/friend'). It can denote
>   'skill; act; power' (scholarship 'the
>   acts of a scholar'; horsemanship 'the
>   skill of a horseman'). It can denote
>   'number' (readership; listenership
>   'number of readers/listeners'). It can
>   denote 'profession; office; position'
>   (professorship 'the profession of a
>   professor'). It can denote rank or
>   title (ladyship; lordship).
>
> The suffix was common in Old English,
>   and is ultimately a form of the
>   ancestor of the Modern English verb
>   shape, in the sense 'to create; form'.
>   Cognate suffixes are found in many
>   Germanic languages; a form
>   occasionally encountered is the German
>   Wissenschaft 'science', from Wissen
>   'knowledge' and -schaft '-ship'.

Comment: -1 Would a "No" do for an answer? I thought the question was actually a non-Q. Next thing I could ask if "or" and "are" are distant cousins.

Answer (score 18):

For the hardcore etymologists who don't feel like looking this up and to complement the top answer, here's the etymologies of *(-)ship* from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ship).

#### ship:

> before 900; (noun) Middle English; Old English scip;  cognate with Dutch schip,  German Schiff,  Old Norse, Gothic skip;  (v.) Middle English s ( c ) hip ( p ) en,  derivative of the noun
>
> O.E. scip  "ship, boat," from P.Gmc. *skipan  (cf. O.N., O.S., Goth. skip , Dan. skib , Swed. skepp , M.Du. scip , Du. schip , O.H.G. skif , Ger. Schiff ), perhaps originally "tree cut out or hollowed out," and derived from PIE base ***skei-  "to cut, split**." The O.E. word was used for small craft as well; in 19c., distinct from a boat  in having a bowsprit and three masts, each with a lower, top, and topgallant mast. Fr. esquif , It. schifo  are Gmc. loan-words. Ship-board  "side of a ship" is from c.1200. Ship-shape  "properly arranged" first attested 1644. Phrase ships that pass in the night  is from Longfellow's poem "Aftermath" (1873). Phrase runs a tight ship  is attested from 1971.

#### -ship:

> Middle English, Old English -scipe;  akin to shape; cognate with dialectal Frisian, dialectal Dutch schip
>
> O.E. -sciepe , Anglian -scip  "state, condition of being," from P.Gmc. *-skapaz  (cf. O.N. -skapr , O.Fris. -skip , Du. -schap , Ger. -schaft ), from base ***skap-  "to create, ordain, appoint**." Cognate with O.E. gesceape

Comment: The answer seems to be "No".

Comment: @Emre ha yeah. they both share a fork at different *scip*'s.