# How did the word "sheer" come to have such different meanings?

Tags: etymology, adjectives

There are `sheer cliffs` and `sheer fabrics`. Why does the same word mean "vertical" in one case and "transparent" in the other? Did they develop from different roots? And what about `sheer obstinancy` and the like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Sheer* - *Shear* itself has actually two different roots.

However, all the examples you have mentioned come from just one of them:

- *Sheer* is a survival of Old English *scīr* "bright", "shining", which came ultimately from the Germanic base *ski-, source also of English shimmer and shine.  Hence for instance the **sheer fabrics**.
- The 'pure' sense also evolves into "genuine" or "intense" and this explains the use in **sheer obstinacy**.
- Similarly it also justifies the use in **sheer cliff** (steep cliff) because it intensifies the main characteristic of a cliff - how abrupt it is.

The second root of *sheer* as  "swerve" probably originated as a variant of shear, which itself comes from Proto Germanic **skeran*, which also evolved into
German and Dutch scheren.  And we are [back to Proto Indo European **sker-*
"cut"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21253/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-scips/21737#21737), which has also produced English *score*, *share*, *ship*, *shirt*, *short*, and *skirt*.

Comment: So, is "sheer fabric" really transparent fabric, or shining/shimmering fabric? Or must it be both, like organza? Or is it enough to be transparent, although the root meant something else?

Comment: @rumtscho, Both.  When fabric making was a manual task, the coarse fabric was made of thick thread and therefore thick and opaque. Conversely, using the finest thread resulted in a thin, shiny or transparent aspect.