# What are the many meanings of the suffix -ship and can it reasonably be applied to the end of most all words?

Tags: suffixes, pirate-english

I'm fascinated by the suffix *-ship* and while it theoretically has no connection to the noun "ship", all definitions provided by [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-ship) seem to in fact not be terms that would be out of place on the deck.

There are a great many [words which end in *-ship*](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-ship&pageuntil=EMIRSHIP%0Aemirship#mw-pages) and I wonder if this suffix might not in fact truly be a vessel with some cargo of mysterious treasure held within. In my personal life I often create new words and have become fond of the idea of creating new types of *-ships.* I do not prefer relationships and friendships over extraordinaryships.

I'm shocked at how difficult it is to construct new *-ship* words and I would like to learn about the factors that influence whether a word can be suffixed with *-ship.*

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ship_3

Comment: Welcome! Interesting question. Could you reframe with a particular answerable question? This site isn't oriented toward opinion-based discussion. (I just don't want you to get close voted?)

Comment: as @Unrelated mentioned, [Stack Exchange sites are not designed for discussion-oriented questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). I edited the end of your post to try to make it fit better into a Q&A format. If you aren't satisfied with my edit, you can also edit the post further.

Comment: Extraordinaryships? I don't think so. Sorry for the apparent oneupmanship.

Comment: WS Gilbert included a pun on these meanings in [The First Lord's Song](http://www.guntheranderson.com/v/data/firstlor.htm) from HMS Pinafore: _Of legal knowledge I acquired such a grip/
That they took me into the **partnership** /
And that junior partnership I ween/
Was the only **ship** that I ever had seen/
But that kind of ship so suited me/
That now I am the Ruler of the Queen's Navy_

Comment: Hi Ben, you've no idea how much of a gem your little fact is to my self as I am a humble pirate king.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback and edits. I'm a computer programmer by trade so am likely to ruffle a few feathers on here. To my credit I have written one novel in my day and shall do my best to behave.

Comment: Spaceship is the word I was primarily referring to. I am interested in the mystery there and I truly believe it must be a matter of entomology rather than alegorical pursuit? Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: Drunkenship is perhaps also to be considered for any notable man's vocabulary.

Comment: @idiotprovider Spaceship is an example of a vessel built for an environment other than water. This is like _airship_  and _landship_. Landship was the original name of the military tank and was similar to _warship_. This is completely different from _friendship_, _partnership_, fellowship and so on which are to do with interactions between people or the status of an individual.

Comment: Agreed. According to the accepted answer there are five different forms of the suffix and there is a real possibility of the construction of new kinds of ships. I'm fond of crowdsurfmanship and also a crowdsurfship could likely make a lot of sense at a rock concert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The etymology of this suffix is given at length by the OED -

> Etymology: In Old English **-sciepe, -skiepe*  (rare), *-scipe, -scype*, Anglian *-scip,* (occas. *-sciop*) strong masculine = Old Frisian
>   *-skipi , -skip, -schip*  (West Frisian *-skip , -schip,* North Frisian *-⁠skep, -skap*), Old Saxon *-scepi , -scipi ,* Middle Low German, Middle Dutch *-sc(h)ip, -sc(h)êpe, -⁠sc(h)eep, -sc(h)êp,* West Flemish
>   *-schip, -schepe*  < Germanic **skapi-z,* < *skap-*  to create, ordain, appoint (see shape v.). The *ĭ* of the stem-syllable of Old English
>   *scipe* and the corresponding continental forms is apparently due to
>   secondary influence of the umlaut, the change being probably favoured
>   by the lack of stress. The related **skapo-z*  (masculine), **skapō* 
>   (feminine), and **skapti-z* shaft n.1, meaning ‘creation, creature,
>   constitution, condition’, were used in Germanic as the second element
>   of compounds and as such assumed the function and meaning of a suffix
>   equivalent to **skapi-z;* these forms are represented by Old Saxon *-skap*
>   (Middle Dutch, Dutch *-schap*), Old High German *-scaf* (feminine), later
>   *-scaft* (Middle High German, German *-schaft*), Old Norse *-skapr* (Danish *-skab,* Swedish *-skap*); the alleged Old English *landsceap* is an error due to misreading.  The abnormal forms of the suffix in Scots
>   *hussyskap, -⁠skep, -skip*  (see housewifeship n.) may have a Low
>   German or Dutch origin.

The important part of that is perhaps the meanings of ***creation, creature, constitution, condition***.

Five separate nuanced senses are given but they are all clearly related, meaning ***the state or condition of being***. Examples of each vary from 1.adjectival, DRUNKENSHIP, HARDSHIP, WORSHIP 2. added to nouns FRIENDSHIP, LORDSHIP 3. Designating person of rank REEVESHIP 4. State of life, occupation or behaviour CLERKSHIP, COURTSHIP, 5. Added to nouns forming compounds TOWNSHIP (this is the only modern example given, and I don't fully understand the distinction from 2.)

**I am not sure if this answers the question, but it does provide some etymology, and the manner in which the suffix is used. Further words I feel sure could be created if they fell within one of those categories, and there are plenty more in everyday use e.g. ACQUAINTENCESHIP. But how about DRIVERSHIP e.g He handed over to another member of the party the *drivership* of the vehicle**?

Comment: Some of the examples seem, to me, to be in the wrong categories. I would consider LORDSHIP to be an example of a designation of rank and REEVESHIP to be an example of occupation rather than rank. Also WORSHIP, although it is used adjectivally in the case of "his worship the mayor" is more fundamentally a behaviour as in "an act of worship". In fact the most common use of _worship_ is as a verb as in "Worship The Lord!" and "He worshipped the ground she walked on".

Comment: @BoldBen I tend to agree. But my examples were taken from the OED - to which if you are a UK Council-Tax payer, and member of your local library, you will almost certainly have free on-line access

Comment: Good answer. Of course the second part of my question regarding the appendage of suffixes to any word is sort of ridiculous but I was ultimately looking for this kind of explanation. I like that as humans we have the right and responsibility to invent new words like grok, as terrible as that may be. I came up with a good one last night: accompanymentship. It's nonsensical and longwinded enough to attempt to define the goofy way I'd like to interact with young ladies as an alternative to the words relationship, or friendship. Thank you.

Comment: @WS2 I appreciated the source. I just thought the examples were poor for such an august publication. Glad you feel much the same.